# Playready for MP4 content

Tags: mp4, drm, playready

Are there any tools available for adding Playready protection to MP4 content?

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that simply encrypting the video won't help. You still need the PlayReady license server that delivers the content encryption key to the player.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Microsoft Expression Encoder to convert MP4 -> WMV.
Then you need to obtain PlayReady SDK and run the encryptor to encrypt the WMV file.

This will given you what you need.

If you need to protect the content in order to share via adaptive streaming use a Transformation Manager IIS extension.

Comment: This is not correct. You don't have to convert it to WMV. The expression encoder can create .ismv files which are playready protected mp4 files.

Comment: This is not correct either. ISMV are not playready protected - these are just files for smooth streaming.
You'll need to run IIS Transform Manager job to make them PlayReady protected.

Comment: You are right. My wording is wrong here - it should be: The expression can create encrypted & playready protected .ismv files. These files are suitable for 'download protected file'-use-case. And yes: You can also put the files on an IIS together with ismc and ism file to stream them. BTW.: my downvote was too harsh.